# how to check session value(exist for user) in ASPState database using sql server session management

Tags: asp.net, web-farm, sql-session-state

We had implemented web farms with SQL server session management for my asp.net applications. Some time this implementation is not working fine.

I want to know how can i check session value(exist for user) in ASPState database because i was suspected that my session are not going in ASPState database.
User is getting problem in 2 out of 10 time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the ASPStateTempSessions table in your SQL Server Session DB and locate your value by SessionId. To be more precise, SessionId in ASPStateTempSessions table is a varchar concatenation of Asp.Net session id + ApplicationId. You can find out more on this page :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx

(Updated with comment from Matthew: ASPStateTempSessions.SessionId = ASP.NET SessionId + ApplicationId)

Comment: Critical point for me was that SessionId in the table is a varchar concatenation of Asp.Net session id +  ApplicationId.